# Is it possible to create a canvas path, flip it, and THEN apply a fill? (in that order)

Tags: html, canvas

Is it possible to create a canvas path, flip it, and then apply a fill?

It needs to be in that particular order.

**Example:**

1. I draw a path. Let's say it's a car. I **don't** fill the path (so nothing is visible)
2. I flip the path
3. I now fill the path with a gradient, so that the gradient is always in the same angle

**Edit:**
I have tried making a temporary canvas with an "unfilled" path, flipped it, and then used this to apply it to the "real" canvas:

```
 ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas,0,0,canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
```

I have then applied my fill like this:

```
ctx.fill();
```

The canvas remains empty. I don't know exacly why. I guess it's not possible in some way?

Comment: What is stopping you from trying?

Comment: I have already tried fo quiet some time now.
I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: I have edited my question with what I have tried

Comment: why do want to draw a path in a way that one cannot see it? Why don't you rotate the path and draw it when you want to make it visible? -- what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Mainly for performance reasons. Calculating the rotated/flipped position for each flipped/changed point in a complex path everytime is both complicated and resource demanding.
I am also creating a collection of functions that will make these kind of things a lot easier in the future.

I want everything except the styles to be rotated/flipped, so that a gradient is always darker at the bottom regardless of how the object is rotated/flipped.

I was going to attach an image for your convenience but unfourtunatly I haven't got enough points to do it:)

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?  You could also create a JSFiddle to give people who want to help you a head start.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

You can flip the canvas horizontally **before** drawing and then everything you draw **after** that is flipped.

No performance penalty!

Of course, before you do the flip, you'll want to context.save() and after the draw you'll want to context.restore() so further drawings are on the un-flipped canvas.

To flip the canvas before the draw, you do the following transforms:

```
context.translate(canvas.width,0);
context.scale(-1,1);
```

Here is the code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/nFvaU/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
    img{border:1px solid blue;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        var img=new Image();
        img.onload=function(){

            // 1. Save the un-flipped canvas
            ctx.save();

            // 2. Flip the canvas horizontally
            ctx.translate(canvas.width,0);
            ctx.scale(-1,1);

            // 3. Draw the image -- or you're path of a car
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

            // 4. Restore the canvas so further draws are not flipped horizontally
            ctx.restore();

        }
        img.src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/139992952/car.png";

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Original Image</p>
    <img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/139992952/car.png" width=200 height=78>
    <p>Horizontally flipped Image on Canvas</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=78></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```